# TypeScript: Return different function based on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

What I want to achieve is a hook that returns me a function that I can call.

```js
type TypeName = 'circle' | 'square';

interface Circle {
  type: TypeName;
  radius: number;
}

interface Square {
  type: TypeName;
  length: number;
}

type Shape = Circle | Square;

const useShapeFilter = (shape: Shape) => {
  const circleFilter = (circle: Circle) => (circle.radius < 5);

  const squareFilter = (square: Square) => (square.length < 5);

  return {applyFilter: shape.type === 'circle' ? circleFilter : shape.type === 'square' ? squareFilter : undefined}
}

export const ShapeComponent = () => {
  const shape: Circle = {type: 'circle', radius: 10}
  const {applyFilter} = useShapeFilter(shape);

  return <div>Less than 5 : {applyFilter && applyFilter(shape)}</div>
}
```

But the above will return a TypeScript error at the `applyFilter(shape)` area: `Argument of type 'Circle' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Circle & Square'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'Circle' but required in type 'Square'.`.

In the end, I had to change the implementation and assert the data:

```js
const useShapeFilter = (shape: Shape) => {
  const circleFilter = (circle: Circle) => (circle.radius < 5);

  const squareFilter = (square: Square) => (square.length < 5);

  if (shape.type === 'circle') {
    return circleFilter(shape as Circle)
  }
  if (shape.type === 'square') {
    return squareFilter(shape as Square)
  }
  return undefined;

}

export const AnimalPage = () => {
  const shape: Circle = {type: 'circle', radius: 10}
  const filtered = useShapeFilter(shape);

  return <div>Less than 5 : {filtered}</div>
}
```

But I'm still wondering how to achieve my original intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are returning a union of functions without any relation to the original parameter, typescript can't really follow the fact that `shape` will actually fit into `applyFilter`. Generally if a variable can hold any one of two functions it is only safe to call the variable with and argument would be valid for EITHER one of the potential underlying functions.

To get around this we could  make `useShapeFilter` generic, capture the original  parameter, and return a function that will be compatible with that specific argument:

```
function useShapeFilter<T extends Shape>(shape: T): { applyFilter: (shape: T) => boolean; } 
function useShapeFilter(shape: Shape) {
  const circleFilter = (circle: Circle) => (circle.radius < 5);

  const squareFilter = (square: Square) => (square.length < 5);

  return {applyFilter: shape.type === 'circle' ? circleFilter : shape.type === 'square' ? squareFilter : undefined}
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFAwCeYWcAKo1gHLIjMC85uYFFwAbLGTgAfcqgCOAV2SUyAbho1gAOxhYoBPMwDCQ0cwDeNOHAZMAXK3Zceaq1GQATYPNT3N8kABGumoAvupaOnoGcADKCkrmltbs9mxMTlgucGKaAOYwABa+-kFQoeo2zDEFyExw-MbCYlKx8ZRqNATymvjAEJpw3ljVtVgAYsAikQA8LHBYAB46mu7oI0wAfAAUqDV2rACU9mYoYGAi9BNTuvY7e1ipB-UbcAEQEGLImipwIXCd3V6-UGqGG9yukTuo3s6ywTwsVlw-VQ8EETXGk0i9TgWzRpnsjVMT14L1xJjEADo3J5vHBpnAAKwHDqI5HwOSKSgQ3TYnZtB6tTlw544jkJCk5fIFOmM5nqVxYGDyKADMy1c6XTE3OC7UYUyr1Xj8Mh4sQSAD8cFNGOuUDg9l1TH17ENxrFyjglvdNqx9m67iwBC0WHcYTCNEWkFgVrZsXuhhIkE0WG0vOJLwRMc0KJ19wJ5L4cDMlXsJoLZAANHBqV4fHAAIwABjCrOz8DVZwu3Kgf34Q1h3ahTDlSUoSpVdM8ADcNgAZLCodCFL6M+1F9VdrV2gBk29OGsHjrhIWmAHppxsaCEgA)